# Can I create a view against a table on another instance?

Tags: sql-server-2000, view

I need to query a table from another SQL Server on a different server but same domain, but I am not sure how I will be able to do it.

I tried the solution [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573796/can-i-create-view-in-my-database-server-from-another-database-server) but it doesn't work for me as I got SQL Server 2000 (please don't hate :-) ).

When I try solution given then I get this error:

> Line 23: Incorrect syntax near '-'.

Which is because command is not compatible with SQL Server 2000.

**Edit**

```
SELECT * FROM AnotherServer.AnotherServerDatabase.Server.Table1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess here, and the problem is not that your command is "not compatible" but rather that your linked server name, or database name, or table name contains a `-`. To fix this, you surround it with `[square brackets]`.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.viewname
AS
  SELECT column_names_please_not_*
    FROM [AnotherServer].[AnotherServerDatabase].dbo.[Table1];
```

Of course, first, you need to have a linked server created and set up appropriately in terms of permissions.